# "reentrant call to SetCurrentCellAddressCore" in event handlers - only where cell row and column indices are equal

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, datagridview, event-handling

I am making a WinForms application which includes a form that uses a `DataGridView` to handle simple data manipulation. To ensure accurate entry while mitigating clutter (read: without using `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`) I have a couple event handlers which temporarily turn a `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` into an equivalent `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` connected to values known to be "clean" when editing events are raised (typically when an editable cell is clicked):

```
private void OnCellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //construct a textbox cell and set to current value
    DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    cell.Value = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;

    //color row if invalid or modified
    UpdateRowStyle(dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex]);

    //switch to the new cell and redraw
    dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] = cell;
    dataGridView.Refresh();
}
```

and

```
private void OnCellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    //construct a combobox cell, link to data, and set to current value
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
    cell.DataSource = mDropDownValues[dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name];
    cell.Value = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;

    //switch to the new cell and redraw
    dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] = cell;
    dataGridView.Refresh();
}
```

Most of the time this works perfectly - the last cell edited reverts to a `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` containing the newly selected data, and the cell selected for editing becomes a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` linked to the data specified in the `mDropDownValues[]` dictionary. When editing a cell which has row and column indices that are equal, however, I run into trouble. The cell fails to change between the two types, throwing an exception on the `dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] = cell;` line in both event handlers (once when handling `CellBeginEdit` and then again when handling`CellEndEdit`). The exception states

> "Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function."

What is causing this error, and why does it only happen when editing the cells along the `DataGridView`'s diagonal? Is there some way I can achieve this functionality without throwing this exception?

Comment: Using .NET 4.5.1 and developing for Win7 if that has any bearing upon your answers.

Answer (score 6):

You are doing battle with this statement in SetCurrentCellAddressCore(), edited for readability:

```
        // Allow the code to be re-entrant only as a result of
        // underlying data changing.
        if (this.dataGridViewOper[DATAGRIDVIEWOPER_inCurrentCellChange] && 
           (this.dataConnection == null || !this.dataConnection.ProcessingListChangedEvent))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.DataGridView_SetCurrentCellAddressCoreNotReentrant));
        }
```

The DATAGRIDVIEWOPER_inCurrentCellChange flag is true.  DataGridView has a lot of these kind of checks, no doubt added after extensive testing.  It limits the number of things you can do *while* an event is raised, ensuring that the re-entrancy does not corrupt internal state of the control.

The universal solution to these kind of re-entrancy problems is to perform the operation later, after the event is raised and the internal state of the control is stable again.  You can do so elegantly with the BeginInvoke() method, it runs when your program re-enters the dispatcher loop.  Like this:

```
private void OnCellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
        //construct a textbox cell and set to current value
        DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        cell.Value = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;

        //color row if invalid or modified
        UpdateRowStyle(dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex]);

        //switch to the new cell and redraw
        dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] = cell;
        dataGridView.Refresh();
    }));
}
```

Comment: When wrapping the contents of the event handlers in `BeginInvoke()` I no longer get the error when editing a cell on the diagonal, but the cells no longer switch to `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`s when selected for editing either. I'm guessing that this has to do with the asynchronous call, but I'm  not sure... any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, no, that's mysterious and I didn't repro that.  You didn't give OnCellBeginEdit() the same treatment, did you?  Not necessary.

Comment: Yes, I did. After removing the `BeginInvoke()` wrapper for OnCellBeginEdit, however, I still get the error the handler is called.

Comment: That's possible I suppose, I had no idea what exactly you do to put the cell into edit mode.  The one I tested, just typing a character, makes little sense in practice.  Update your question with that detail.

Comment: I was just using the edit event raised by clicking on the cell. Added to question body as well.