# Filtering of combobox - weird behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a combobox in my WinForms application in which you can search for a string and results are filtered accordingly, but it seems to behave very strangely. I am searching for "Coo" and I get a very long list of products that do not contain the string "coo" (http://prntscr.com/pr54rs). However, when I type in "coor" and then press backspace, leaving me with "coo" again, the list of results is different (http://prntscr.com/pr55ef)

I am using the "KeyPress" event handler to search in the combobox. The code looks like this

```
 private void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        listNew.Clear();
        var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        foreach (var item in listOnit)
        {
            if (item.ToLower().Contains(this.comboBox1.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                listNew.Add(item);
            }
        }

        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(listNew.ToArray());
        comboBox1.SelectionStart = this.comboBox1.Text.Length;
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong? The list is populated from a database

```
 string sqlProducts = "SELECT Description FROM stocktake_products WHERE stocktake_id = '" + stocktakeID.stocktake_id + "' AND (PLUProdCode IS NULL OR PLUProdCode = '');";
            MySqlCommand cmdProduct = new MySqlCommand(sqlProducts, conn);
            cmdProduct.CommandTimeout = 10000;
            MySqlDataReader rdrProduct = cmdProduct.ExecuteReader();
            AutoCompleteStringCollection myCollectionSales1 = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            if (rdrProduct.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (rdrProduct.Read())
                {
                   // myCollectionSales1.Add(rdrProduct[0].ToString());
                    listOnit.Add(rdrProduct[0].ToString());
                }
                rdrProduct.Close();
                //textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = myCollectionSales1;
                comboBox1.Items.AddRange(listOnit.ToArray());

            }
```

I want the combobox to only display results that contain the whole string that has been typed in, not every phrase that has typed letters in any position as it seems like that's what it is doing.

I have tried to include the BeginIvoke method (not sure if done correctly thought as I have never used it before)

```
this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            listNew.Clear();
            var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

            foreach (var item in listOnit)
            {
                if (item.ToLower().Contains(this.comboBox1.Text.ToLower()))
                {
                    listNew.Add(item);
                }
            }

            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(listNew.ToArray());
            comboBox1.SelectionStart = this.comboBox1.Text.Length;
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
        });
```

Now when I start typing the first character, the combobox selects to top result right away (http://prntscr.com/pr5f6i). I have to press the first character again and then type the rest of the string to be able to actually search through the list.

Comment: It is just a simple misunderstanding how KeyPress works.  It fires *before* the character gets added, so when you type "coo" then you'll search for "co".  Elegantly fixed by using this.BeginInvoke() so the code runs after the keystroke is processed.

Comment: When do I add the this.BeginInvocek()? Right after the handler definition?

Comment: In the KeyPress event handler.  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27661319/17034).

Comment: I've done that with slightly different code. I used the example you provided and the result is still the same. When I start typing the first character, the combobox selects to top result right away (http://prntscr.com/pr5f6i). I have to press the first character again and then type the rest of the string to be able to actually search through the list.

Comment: The list is populated from the database on each keystroke. But if user types "coor" they are not interested in three filters for "c", "co", and "coo". I suggest you start filtering only after a small delay of inactivity, maybe a second. If user types fast enough they will have a better experience. Also, it would be good if you can stop current DB activity if user presses a new key.